# Reference Line with GD::GRAPH

Tags: perl, graphing

I created a bar chart for students. Now I want to have a cutoff line where it shows that this is the everything below  this is a failing grade. A horizontal line on at point 35 on Y-AXIS is what I'm trying to have. Any suggestions? This is what I currently have

```
my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new(800, 800);

  @data = ( 
  ["Jack","Jill"],
  ['30','50'],
    );

 $graph->set( 
    x_label           => 'Students',
    y_label           => 'Scores',
    title             => 'Student Vs. Scores',
   y_max_value       => 60,
   y_tick_number     => 8,
   y_label_skip      => 2 
  ) or die $graph->error;


my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;

open(IMG, '>file.png') or die $!;
 binmode IMG;
 print IMG $gd->png;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mixed graph with two datasets, one for your regular data and one for the cutoff line. Set the `types` option to `$graph->set` to `[qw(bars lines)]` (putting the bar graph dataset first). According to the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm), "Bar graphs drawn after lines or points graphs may obscure the earlier data". (I haven't tried this yet but I think it should work).

```
my @data = ( 
    ["Jack", "Jill"],
    [30, 50],
    [35, 35]  # Cutoff line
);

my $graph = GD::Graph::mixed->new(800, 800);

$graph->set( 
    x_label           => 'Students',
    y_label           => 'Scores',
    title             => 'Student Vs. Scores',
    y_max_value       => 60,
    y_tick_number     => 8,
    y_label_skip      => 2,
    types             => [qw(bars lines)]
) or die $graph->error;

my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;
```

By default, line graphs will still draw even if some of the points in your dataset are `undef`. This means you only need to give a value for the first and last points on the line. For example, if there are five students, the y-values for the cutoff line would look like

```
[35, undef, undef, undef, 35]
```

**EDIT:** This approach leaves a gap at the beginning and end of the line because it is only drawn to the middle of the first and last bars. However, this [perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=341982) explains a couple of methods for creating a vertical line that I imagine would adapt to a horizontal line easily enough. Be warned, both methods are ugly hacks.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I ended up with a small line in the middle of the graph. I tried adding 

    my @data = ( 
    ["Jack", "Jill"],
    [30, 50],
    [35, 35, 35, 35 ,35, 35]  # Cutoff line

But that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: @LeRay You need to have the same number of points in each dataset, so if you only have two bars, you can only have two points in the other dataset. Also, the image you linked to is blank.

Comment: ah, so that means i'm stuck. Since the line that it creates starts from the middle of one bar and ends in the middle of the second bar. No other way to have a straight cut off line?

Comment: @LeRay Adding a hidden (i.e. value = `undef`) bar at the beginning and end of your dataset and playing with the [bar_width and bar_spacing options](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm#Options_for_graphs_with_bars) might work, but would probably not be pretty. For an alternative (still hackish) solution, see my latest edit.